# Is there a way to push a Docker container from DockerHub to Google App Engine?

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I'm looking for a way to use `gcloud app deploy...`  to directly grab a Docker address from Docker Hub and deploy straight to Google App Engine.  If there's no way, that's fine but I thought I'd check here.

I looked around and didn't see a way to do this directly.  It seems that I have to push the container from Docker Hub to Google Container Registry then from there I can run `gcloud app deploy --image-url=[HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]` to deploy.

This is according to https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling#pushing_an_image_to_a_registry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a better idea to just use a Compute Engine instance.  I can push a container from a public source or public/private from Container Registry.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers#prepare